# Do females living on mountains have more RBCs than a normal male

Tags: hematology, red-blood-cell

I got this doubt when I was studying about [haematocrit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematocrit) value. According to my NCERT textbook males have greater number of RBCs than females. But who will have more RBCs when comparing a normal male and a female who lives at a higher altitude?

*edit

the magnitude of altitude would be less than [8,586 m (28,169 ft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangchenjunga)) as the woman I know is not exactly at the top summit of [Kanchenjunga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangchenjunga) so what would be the answer then?

Comment: Why should it be different there?

Comment: @Chris i didn't get you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_adaptation

Comment: @Raghavakrishna i have read that article but my doubt is who will have more no. of RBCs now a normal male living at normal sea level or a female living at higher altitude? because normally males have more no or RBCs when compared with females

Comment: @agharehanabbas You can not compare this directly since the conditions are completely different. And if men and women are both at high altitude, I would expect men again to have higher counts.

Comment: @agharehanabbas May be this could be useful http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11256567

Comment: your edits still do not provide enough clarification and suggest that it is medical advice you seek (it regards someones specific RBC count).

Comment: @GriffinEvo what more should i add in my question then

Comment: Specific altitudes that you had in mind. The male and female. <8586m is not specific, it is anywhere from 0-8586.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently impossible to give a definite answer... It depends what altitude you look at.

Going from @Alan_boyd's answer the normal range is 40-50% for males and 36-44% for females. If the altitude at which a person is acclimatized to correlates well with red blood cell count (RBCC), and this effect is not gender specific (i.e. both sexes are affected similarly), then an average woman from high altitude should have a higher RBCC than an average from low altitude. But whether or not the high altitude female RBCC exceeds that of the male depends on the altitude of the two measured.

This rough graph, *[assuming RBCC and altitude correlate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_training) and that [male RBCC is higher than female RBCC](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003646.htm)*, shows the problem. Female (red dashed line) A is from a higher altitude than the selected male (blue dashed line) and has lower RBCC. Female (red dashed line) B is from a higher altitude than the selected male (blue dashed line) and has higher RBCC.

[image]

**Define altitudes and the question may be answerable.**

Comment: i have edited my question now what must be the answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MedlinePlus site](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003646.htm) these are the normal ranges for haematocrit:

Male: 40.7 - 50.3%

Female: 36.1 - 44.3%

Unfortunately it isn't clear if these ranges are for people living at low altitude, but since most people in the USA do, I think this is a safe inference. So clearly there is already some overlap.

The paper accessible [here](http://www.jpp.krakow.pl/journal/archive/11_07_s5/pdf/811_11_07_s5_article.pdf) reports various changes in haematocrit due to moving between different altitudes. Broadly speaking these changes are in the range of 10 - 15 percentage points (e.g. a change from 39% to 49%).

So yes, a female who has moved to a high altitude is likely to experience an erythrocytosis (or polycythaemia) which would mean that her haematocrit would exceed that of many males.